# insert letter before vowel in word

Tags: python-3.3

how to insert letter before vowel in each word in python. like Gibberish game. We have to ask user to to input some letter and input their word to insert some letter that they input at first to before vowels in each word they input at second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is for homework, you really should try to figure this out on your own rather than going to StackOverflow, but you can use regex to do it in one line:

```
import re
re.sub(r"([aeiou])",r"X\g<1>", "hello")
```

Or if you want a function version of it:

```
import re
def add_letter_to_vowels(word, letter):
  return re.sub(r"([aeiou])",r"%s\g<1>"%letter, word)
```

Then it runs as follows:

```
>>> add_letter_to_vowels("hello", "X")
'hXellXo'
```

Regular expressions are very powerful, [read more about them here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) and the [API reference is here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Comment: it doesn't work in python